# statuscode 400 reasonphrase 'bad request' version 1.1

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms

I'm having this simple POST method using WCF and Xamarin. Forms. I've tried different approaches of formatting and sending data, and web configuration on the server side, but I still get bad request error. Here's my code on the client side:

```
        OrderContract order = new OrderContract
        {
            OrderID = "10550",
            OrderDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
            ShippedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
            ShipCountry = "india",
            OrderTotal = "781"
        };


        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://ipaddress/Services/OrderService.svc/PlaceOrder"));
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, httpContent);
        await DisplayAlert("", result.ToString(), "OK");
```

and my code on the server side:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/PlaceOrder",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
    void PlaceOrder(OrderContract order);
```

and my web.config:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <service name="PortalRestService.OrderService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="PortalRestService.IOrderService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
        var s = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject,s);
```